# how to parse server socket input stream to get json object?

Tags: android, rest, http, android-json

In my android app, I have a listener thread which listens for anything posted over a server socket. Once something is posted (I use HttpRequester tool to POST any message), I get the input stream. I am able to see my json inside the input stream but cannot find a way to parse to get the json object out of it.

Here is my code sample doing it:

```
iMessageListenerThread = new Thread() {
            public void run(){
                // wait till user connects to server
                try
                {
                    iServerSocket = new ServerSocket();
                    iServerSocket.setReuseAddress(true);
                    iServerSocket.bind(new InetSocketAddress(mPort));
                    Log.d(TAG,"Server Socket opened" );

                    try {
                        for (;;) {
                            Socket ss = iServerSocket.accept(); // unblocks when connection is requested
                            // test if something received, if so, display this
                            InputStream localInputStream = ss.getInputStream();
                            if(localInputStream == null){
                                Log.d(TAG,"LOCAL INPUT STREAM NULL" );
                                continue;
                            }


                            //localInputStream = new GZIPInputStream(localInputStream);
                            String resultstring = convertStreamToString(localInputStream);
-----
-----


    private String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
        String line = "";
        StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        try {
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                total.append(line+"\n");
                total.append(line);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Stream Exception", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return total.toString();
    }
```

In the HttpRequester tool, i put the following url:
http://xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:8000/powerstate

and in the content section, I put this json:

{"powerstate":"on"}

---

This is my response string containging the json object:

```
I/RecorderService( 1518): ...resultstring : POST /powerstate HTTP/1.1
I/RecorderService( 1518): POST /powerstate HTTP/1.1Host: 192.168.21.240:8000
I/RecorderService( 1518): Host: xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:8000User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:30.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/30.0
I/RecorderService( 1518): User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:30.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/30.0Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
I/RecorderService( 1518): Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
I/RecorderService( 1518): Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
I/RecorderService( 1518): Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflateContent-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
I/RecorderService( 1518): Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8Content-Length: 19
I/RecorderService( 1518): Content-Length: 19Connection: keep-alive
I/RecorderService( 1518): Connection: keep-alivePragma: no-cache
I/RecorderService( 1518): Pragma: no-cacheCache-Control: no-cache
I/RecorderService( 1518): Cache-Control: no-cache
I/RecorderService( 1518): {"powerstate":"on"}
```

Can someone help me to know how to extract json object from this inputstream

Comment: Are you saying convertStreamToString() method returns an empty string or null?

Comment: @serkan .. No it returns a string which has the header information as well, but I just want the json content from it.

Comment: You read the stream line by line. Just search for a line starting with a { and ending with a }. As extra you can check the line length with content length.

Comment: @greenapps .. thanks for your comment. yes, I have done something like that already but was looking for some standard way to remove the header or extract the json object. Isn't there any starndard way/api to do that?

Comment: @TheCommonGuy Sorry I'm crap shooting here but perhaps the issue is more fundamental that your Android (client) is communicating using a Socket but the server is using HTTP protocol. Usually either end of the communication would use the same method.  HTTP calls will include header and other information (which you don't want).  If you server-side also responded using a socket connection (having a socket port where the client connects to) and only send the json, then your problem could be resolved.

Comment: @serkan. The server also uses a socket connection. The server communicates using the http protocol. The client just has to skip some headers. For the rest there is not much difference.