# parse server socket input stream to get json object

Tags: android, json, sockets

I was trying to use socket to get response from api

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
```

And got response as :

> HTTP/1.1 200 OKServer: nginx/1.8.1Date: Wed, 16 Mar 2016 10:58:33
>   GMTContent-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8Transfer-Encoding:
>   chunkedConnection: keep-aliveSet-Cookie:
>   ci_session=a%3A5%3A%7Bs%3A10%3A%22session_id%22%3Bs%3A32%3A%22b98d2cae90806cadfc2c4e08235e85f6%22%3Bs%3A10%3A%22ip_address%22%3Bs%3A15%3A%22202.166.198.151%22%3Bs%3A10%3A%22user_agent%22%3Bb%3A0%3Bs%3A13%3A%22last_activity%22%3Bi%3A1458125913%3Bs%3A9%3A%22user_data%22%3Bs%3A0%3A%22%22%3B%7D1df5f1fdd7228e520f7b0873b21273df;
>   expires=Wed, 16-Mar-2016 12:58:33 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/Vary:
>   Accept-Encoding389b{"update_date":"2015-04-02
>   05:31:26","status":"success","status_message":"new
>   data","data":[{"cat_id":"1","cat_name":"Art","update_date":"2015-04-02
>   05:30:44","subcat":[]},{"cat_id":"2","cat_name":"Antiques","update_date":"2015-04-02
>   05:30:54","subcat":[]},{"cat_id":"3","cat_name":"Automotive","update_date":"2015-03-19
>   21:11:14","subcat":[]},{"cat_id":"4","cat_name":"Baby","update_date":"2015-03-19
>   21:13:07","subcat":[]},{"cat_id":"5","cat_name":"Books","update_date":"2015-04-02
>   03:09:21","subcat":[]}}

**Now How to get the json only form this response??**
Any standard way to do this apart from getting string from { to }....

Similar question is asked in ([how to parse server socket input stream to get json object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27508283/how-to-parse-server-socket-input-stream-to-get-json-object)) but is not answered.

Answer (score 0):

Why use a raw socket instead of a HTTP connection when you're obviously talking to a web server?

Let some library take care of parsing the HTTP response for you and just get the JSON content of the response:

**With [Google Guava](https://github.com/google/guava)**

Use [`Resources.toString(URL, Charset)`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/io/Resources.html#toString(java.net.URL,%20java.nio.charset.Charset)):

```
URL url = ...
String json = Resources.toString(url, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

You'll need adapt the URL and possibly the charset (if you control the server, make that give you UTF-8 instead of having your app accept something else).

**With [Volley](http://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple.html)**

```
String url = ...
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
    new Response.Listener<String>() {
      @Override
      public void onResponse(String response) {
        // response is your JSON
      }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
      @Override
      public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        // stuff went wrong
      }
    });
queue.add(stringRequest);
```

**With plain Android SDK**

If you really want/have to avoid libraries, take a look at [HttpURLConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) which is the recommended HTTP client for Android 6.0 and beyond: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html

Try to avoid this, because you're more likely in the business of building an app, not in that of writing random IO code that already exists elsewhere (and likely has less bugs and better test coverage).

Comment: thank you fro your response but i was trying to crawl into core of this networking thing...Who knows some day i might build better library than those that are now :)

Comment: I applaud your desire to learn! If you intent to release your app on the Play Store, may I suggest to use one of these libraries instead of rolling your own because you will make mistakes and your users will suffer from them otherwise. For learning, you can read the code of Guava, Volley, Apache HttpClient and HttpURLConnection (it's all open source) and try reimplement parts of it to understand how sockets, networking and HTTP work.

Answer (score -1):

```
     String msg = "";

       BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        try {
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                msg.append(line);                     // get the MSG as String
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Stream Exception", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

int index=line.indexOf('{');  // index from JSON response starts
line=line.substring(index);
JSONObject object=new JSONObject(line);

// from here get your data.
```

Comment: This doesn't work if the JSON response is an array or just a primitive, if any of the headers contain `{`, if the response isn't encoded in whatever default charset Android assumes. It also doesn't close the socket, leaking precious native resources.